# Detect if array contains another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I'm using external API for my website. When user select city and town, API returns neighborhoods. But the problem is, if there is only one neighborhood array contains name and neighborhood id. But if there is more than one, it contains multiple array for each neighborhood.

Single example ;

```
array(
'Code' => 123,
'NeighborhoodName' => 'Name'
)
```

[image]

Multiple Example

```
array(
    array(
    'Code' => 123,
    'NeighborhoodName' => 'Name'
    ),
array(
    'Code' => 123,
    'NeighborhoodName' => 'Name'
    )
```

)
[image]

I have to show data to user inside select box.

```
<select  id="nh" class="form-control" name="belde" wire:model='selectedNH'>
            <option value="" selected default></option>
            
                @foreach($nh as $nhArray)
                     <option value="{{$nhArray['Kod']}}">{{$koyArray['KOY_Adi']}}</option>
                 @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
```

As expected, if there is only one neighborhood, my code throws Illegal string offset 'Kod' error. I tried to gettype for compare array childs but didnt work

Comment: Reformat the API response before passing it to the template. There you can check if you got multiple neighborhoods or only one; if it's only one, wrap it in an additional array so that you always have an array of arrays. That way, your template code stays the same for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if(isset($nh['Kod']))
    <option value="{{ $nh['Kod'] }}">{{ $nh['KOY_Adi'] }}</option>
@else
    @foreach($nh as $nhArray)
        <option value="{{$nhArray['Kod']}}">{{$koyArray['KOY_Adi']}}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Some explanations for the answer: in the if statement, you check the array key ['Kod'], if the array key exists, then you know this all the places are not displayed in the array, and then in the else statement, you do what you did before, to loop through the array.

Comment: please explain the code too, leaving answer saying "try this: " dont help many of the time. This might help the questioner, but for future readers, please add a few lines describing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `is_array()`? You can read more about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php